# sweetalert remove(); on confirmaition

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

I want to run the remove function on  all `checked` `.select-input` when the `.delete` button is pressed and the `confirmButton` is clicked.

```js
$(".delete").click(function() {
  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this lorem ipsum!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    closeOnConfirm: false
  }).then(result => {
    if (result.value) {
      swal("Deleted!", "Your file has been deleted.", "success"),
        function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(".post-list")
            .find(".select-input:checked")
            .closest(".item")
            .remove();
        };
    } else if (
      // Read more about handling dismissals
      result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel
    ) {
      swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.21.1/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.21.1/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<button class="delete">delete</button>
<div class="post-list">
  <div class="item">
    <label>
<input id="post-select1" type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <label>
<input id="item2" type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unknown parameter "closeOnConfirm" I think this stop your next script execution. How about to remove this line closeOnConfirm: false ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove **closeOnConfirm** (it is moved into the button decleration, check this out; https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#buttons ). Use **swall.closeModal();** function for this parameter.

Second; for to check result value, use just **result**. Also, I prefer to use **result==true**. I think, it is better than only **result**.

I hope this will help you...

```js
$(".delete").click(function() {
  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this lorem ipsum!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  }).then(result => {
    swal("Deleted!", "Your file has been deleted.", "success");
    if (result.value) {
      $(".post-list")
      .find(".select-input:checked")
      .closest(".item")
      .remove();
    } else if (
      // Read more about handling dismissals
      result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel
    ) {
      swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
    }
    swall.closeModal();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.21.1/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.21.1/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<button class="delete">delete</button>
<div class="post-list">
  <div class="item">
    <label>
<input id="post-select1" type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <label>
<input id="item2" type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the item

Comment: I didn't check your codes for this, sorry. Check it out again updated answer.

Comment: Hey Serhat, I was using an out of date CDN for sweetalert. Are you able to check again with the latest version?

Comment: Sweetalert is free ware. You dont have to use cdn. You can download .js and .css file as you know. This way will more useful I think. CodeSnipppet is working. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I edited the question snippet with the new CDN. The remove isn't working and the cancel modal is not showing

Comment: The snippet which is in my answer is working good. The most important difference between with yours is that; in your snippet, 9., 13., 14. and 19. lines must close. After close these lines, try your code. It will work!

Comment: See your snippet now. I have added the latest CDN and not touched your code and it is not working.

Comment: After change the new version, you must change to cheking result with result.value.. ok now? Your changes will accepted, after my change codes worked again :)